# Airflow task is stuck in status queued

Tags: python-3.x, airflow, scheduler

Airflow is running but the task is stuck as its status queued.

I ran airflow scheduler.

Here are my code and snapshot of the airflow ui.

Can any one explain to me what the problem would be?

```html
import datetime as dt
from datetime import timedelta

from airflow import DAG
from airflow.operators.bash_operator import BashOperator
from airflow.operators.python_operator import PythonOperator
import pandas as pd

def CSVToJson():
    df = pd.read_csv('/Users/daeyong/Desktop/Projects/Python/airflow2/file.csv')
    for i,r in df.interrows() :
        print(r['name'])
    df.to_json('fromAirflow.json', orient='record')

default_args = {
    'owner': 'paulcrickard',
    'start_date': dt.datetime(2022, 3, 10),
    'retries': 1,
    'retry_delay': dt.timedelta(minutes=5)
}

with DAG('MyCSVDAG',
    default_args=default_args,
    schedule_interval=timedelta(minutes=5),
    # '0 * * * *',
) as dag:
    print_starting = BashOperator(task_id='starting',
    bash_command='echo "I am reading the CSV now....."')
    CSVJson = PythonOperator(task_id='convertCSVtoJson', python_callable=CSVToJson)


print_starting >>  CSVJson
```

[airflow_screenshot_1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/skZbC.png)

[airflow_screenshot_2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pqR3v.png)

Comment: DAG not running can be caused by one of the following:
- DAG is not turned on (toggle switch)
- DAG is not triggered
- Scheduler is not working
- All workers are occupied and the tasks is queued

IT seems you have already triggered the DAG, and turned on the scheduler. Have you switched on the DAG?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: @DaveMartinez I just edit the original question with the image. DAG was turned on. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Two possible reasons without more context.

1. Your default pool does not have any slots assigned or available
2. Your declaration of tasks needs to be tabbed over to fall within the "with DAG" statement

Scheduler logs and an image of your pools page would help more.